# Does not divide correctly

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm trying to divide 20 by 2 but my 6502 computer prints `254254` instead of `10`.
Here's the code:

```
PORTB = $6000
PORTA = $6001
DDRB = $6002
DDRA = $6003

E  = %10000000
RW = %01000000
RS = %00100000

N = $2000   ; 1 byte
D = $2001   ; 1 byte
Q = $2002   ; 1 byte
R = $2003   ; 1 byte

value = $0204       ; 2 bytes
mod10 = $0206       ; 2 bytes
message = $0208     ; 6 bytes

  .org $e000

error_message: .asciiz "An error occured"

loop:
  jmp loop

error:
  ldx #0
error_loop:
  lda error_message, x
  beq loop
  jsr print_char
  inx
  jmp error_loop

print_char:
  jsr lcd_wait
  sta PORTB
  lda #RS
  sta PORTA
  lda #(RS | E)
  sta PORTA
  lda #RS
  sta PORTA
  rts

lcd_wait:
  pha
  lda #%00000000 ; Set all pins on port B to input
  sta DDRB

lcd_busy:
  lda #RW        ; Set RW pin
  sta PORTA
  lda #(RW | E)  ; Set RW and E pins
  sta PORTA
  lda PORTB      ; Read port B
  and #%10000000
  bne lcd_busy

  lda #%11111111 ; Set all pins on port B to output
  sta DDRB
  pla
  rts

lcd_instruction:
  jsr lcd_wait
  sta PORTB
  lda #0         ; Clear RS/RW/E bits
  sta PORTA
  lda #E         ; Set E bit to send instruction
  sta PORTA
  lda #0         ; Clear RS/RW/E bits
  sta PORTA
  rts

divide:
  lda N
  beq error

  lda D
  beq error

  lda N
  cmp D
  bcc error

  lda #0
  sta Q

  lda N
  sta R

divloop:
  sec
  inc Q
  lda R
  sbc D
  sta R
  bcs divloop
  dec Q
  jsr print_R
  jsr print_Q
  rts

print_R:
  lda #0
  sta message

  ; Initialize value to be the number to convert
  lda R
  sta value
  lda #0
  sta value + 1
  jmp divide_int

print_Q:
  lda #0
  sta message

  ; Initialize value to be the number to convert
  lda R
  sta value
  lda #0
  sta value + 1


divide_int:
  ; Initialize the remainder to zero
  lda #0
  sta mod10
  sta mod10 + 1
  clc

  ldx #16


divloop_int:
  ; Rotate quotient and remainder
  rol value
  rol value + 1
  rol mod10
  rol mod10 + 1

  ; a, y = dividend - divisor
  sec
  lda mod10
  sbc #10
  tay   ; save low byte in Y
  lda mod10 + 1
  sbc #0
  bcc ignore_result  ; branch if dividend < divisor
  sty mod10
  sta mod10 + 1


ignore_result:
  dex
  bne divloop_int
  rol value         ; shift in the last bit of the quotient
  rol value + 1

  lda mod10
  clc
  adc #"0"
  jsr push_char

  ; if value != 0, then continue dividing
  lda value
  ora value + 1
  bne divide_int        ; branch if value not zero

  ldx #0
print:
  lda message, x
  beq return
  jsr print_char
  inx
  jmp print

push_char:
  pha  ; Push new first character onto stack
  ldy #0


char_loop:
  lda message, y    ; Get char on string and put into X
  tax
  pla
  sta message, y    ; Pull char off stack and add it to the string
  iny
  txa
  pha               ; Push char from string onto stack
  bne char_loop

  pla
  sta message, y    ; Pull the null off the stack and add to the end of the string
return:
  rts

reset:
  ldx #$ff
  txs

  lda #%11111111 ; Set all pins on port B to output
  sta DDRB
  lda #%11100000
  sta DDRA

  lda #20
  sta N
  lda #2
  sta D

  lda #%11100000 ; Set top 3 pins on port A to output
  sta DDRA
  lda #%00000001 ; Clear display
  jsr lcd_instruction
  lda #%00111000 ; Set 8-bit mode; 2-line display; 5x8 font
  jsr lcd_instruction
  lda #%00001110 ; Display on; cursor on; blink off
  jsr lcd_instruction
  lda #%00000110 ; Increment and shift cursor; don't shift display
  jsr lcd_instruction


  lda #0
  sta message

  jsr divide

  jmp loop


  .org $fffc
  .word reset
  .word $0000
```

I hope someone see my error, I've been debugging for 5 hours now.
My 6502 is inspired from Ben Eater's one.
I use [vasm](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/) as a compiler with the old style syntax.

Comment: Have you checked the division function itself with a debugger / simulator to see if it's the problem, or if printing / IO is the problem?  Have you looked at register values in a debugger to see where large numbers are coming from?

Comment: Dou you want an arbitrary division, or just 2? Because this can be done easily with `lsr`

Comment: @PeterCordes it seems that the problem as to do with memory or division because if you change N or D, it outputs the same number. Also, if you remove `jsr print_R`or `jsr print_Q`the output is `254`.

Comment: @Devolus Arbitrary division.

Comment: Don't just look at the outputs, use a debugger to see exactly how your code is executing, and values in regs.  That's why we have debuggers, and why they're amazingly useful for assembly language.  Debugging without one is like trying to build a robot blindfolded; a waste of your time and everyone else's.  It may take some work to port your code to run in some 6502 emulator/simulator , but very likely worth it to debug parts of it separately.   Also, If a change to the code gives you `254`, then probably your `254254`original output is just that printed twice.  (especially since that's > 2^16)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I really don't understand this. Most of the questions here can be solved easily, just by using a debugger, instead people rather rely on some posted answer.

Comment: @Devolus: Yup, exactly.  The querent here may be testing on actual physical hardware, given the reference to a Ben Eater inspired project, which would mean they can't use a debugger for that way of running their code.  (Presumably homebrewed minimal hardware won't have a JTAG interface.) 
 But that's why we have simulators / emulators, to at least test the hardware-independent parts and watch register values change as you single-step.  Even if you don't have a simulator with the same hardware I/O port addresses / devices, you don't need that for the division algorithm itself.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you have a good emulator to suggest?

Comment: No, I haven't tried any 6502 emulators, but for an ISA that popular I'm sure there are some.  Unfortunately I don't have any suggestion about which ones are good.

Comment: I just tried an emulator. When CPU gets to address $e0f5, line 105 (I think), it loads the value from R (address $2003) and the value from R is 254.

Comment: Also, in both print_R and print_Q, I load the value from R. Changing R to Q in print_Q prints the good answer.

Comment: This is not a minimal example. You are asking a question about divide by 2 (which is a simple shift to the right) but have a lot of lcd code. The error could be in you lcd code.